# Hive Wallet recovery without PIN

Tags: wallet, passphrase, hive

If  I don't have my pin, but I have my 12 word passphrase, how do I recover the wallet without pin?

Comment: Not a good idea to post your passphrase publicly.

Answer (score 1):

As you can find from [the FAQ](https://github.com/hivewallet/hive-js/wiki/Hive-Web-FAQ), the passphrase is the only part you need to access your wallet. The PIN allows easy access from a machine that you've already logged in from (using your full, secure passphrase). You can force Hive to allow you to reset it by clearing your browser cache/data (assuming you're using the web interface; other clients may or may not have an equivalent function), or entering an incorrect PIN five times.

Since you have now made your passphrase [public](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/posts/30045/revisions), **DO NOT CONTINUE TO USE THIS PASSPHRASE** since people can easily steal any money stored there (well, you can log in with it just to see how that works, but don't transfer money to it). Generate a new one, and NEVER reveal it publicly.

Since there's no current balance in your account (I logged in to check, and possibly "steal" it for you before someone else did; I saw one transfer in and one out, 0 balance now), there's nothing to worry about at the moment, as long as you're not planning on sending money to that account again.